# Unable to boot into Ubuntu

Tags: boot, grub2, dual-boot, windows, 13.04

I installed Ubuntu 13.04 and then dual booted it with Windows. Now, when I boot into my system, the selection menu does not come up. Instead, it directly boots into Windows. Is there any way to have them both working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run Ubuntu Live from a CD, DVD or USB stick. Choose "Try Ubuntu" and when its loaded run the program "Boot Repair" from there. And fix the Grub..

Comment: Great! Then make the answer green :P

Answer (score 0):

That is why you usually install ubuntu after installing windows.

Try following the instructions here and it should help.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair